# Mongo Async Driver: How to invoke a method after completion for foreach method

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, mongodb-java

I am writing a program for data migration. I want to invoke a method after complete execution of foreach method.
In below code foreach(migrateJobsBlock, callback) callback method is invoked for every iteration. Is there any way I can invoke a method only after completion of foreach execution.

```
col1.find(filter).forEach(migrateBlock, callback).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var myCursor = db.doc.find( { filter } );

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   //do something
   var obj = myCursor.next()
}
// finished running! can run completion method
```